# correct type for SQL snowflake date

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, snowflake-schema, isodate

I am using an SQL Script to parse a json into a table using dbt. One of the cols had this date value: '2022-02-09T20:28:59+0000'. What would be the correct way to define iso date's data type in Snowflake?

Currently, I just used the `date` type like this in my dbt sql script:

```
JSON_DATA:"situation_date"::date AS MY_DATE
```

but clearly, `date`isn't the correct one because later when I test it using select * , I get this error:

```
SQL Error [100040] [22007]: Date '2022-02-09T20:28:59+0000' is not recognized
```

so I need to know which Snowflake date data type or datetime type suits the best with this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct pulling the "date from JSON" so not so clear cut:

```
SELECT
    '{"date":"2022-02-09T20:28:59+0000"}' as json_str
    ,parse_json(json_str) as json
    ,json:date as data_from_json
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(data_from_json, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS+0000') as date_1
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(substr(data_from_json,1,19), 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS') as date_2
    ;
```

gives the error:

> Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types VARIANT and TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)

Because the type of `data_from_json` as `VARIANT` and the TO_DATE/TO_TIMESTAMP function expect `TEXT` so we need to cast to that

```
SELECT
    '{"date":"2022-02-09T20:28:59+0000"}' as json_str
    ,parse_json(json_str) as json
    ,json:date as data_from_json
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(data_from_json::text, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS+0000') as date_1
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(substr(data_from_json::text,1,19), 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MI:SS') as date_2
    ;
```

If all your timezones are always `+0000` you can just put that in the parse format (like example `date_1`), OR you can truncate that part off (like example `date_2`)

gives:

| JSON_STR | JSON | DATA_FROM_JSON | DATE_1 | DATE_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {"date":"2022-02-09T20:28:59+0000"} | { "date": "2022-02-09T20:28:59+0000" } | "2022-02-09T20:28:59+0000" | 2022-02-09 20:28:59.000 | 2022-02-09 20:28:59.000 |

Answer (score 0):

Using `TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(JSON_DATA:"situation_date", 'format_here')
FROM tab;
```

---

> so I need to know which Snowflake date data type or datetime type suits the best with this one

[TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#timestamp-input-format)

The specific input could be set up on ACCOUNT/USER/SESSION level.

[AUTO Detection of Integer-stored Date, Time, and Timestamp Values](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#auto-detection-of-integer-stored-date-time-and-timestamp-values)

> Avoid using AUTO format if there is any chance for ambiguous results. Instead, specify an explicit format string by:
>
> Setting TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT and other session parameters for dates, timestamps, and times. See Session Parameters for Dates, Times, and Timestamps (in this topic).

Comment: nah this is not what I am looking for. I edited the qs. I need a suitable data type that I can write into my sql script before running dbt

Comment: @x89 You could override the AUTO TIMESTAMP/DATE FORMAT and provide your own

Answer (score 0):

I think `::TIMESTAMP` should work for this. So `JSON_DATA:"situation_date"::TIMESTAMP` if you need to go just to date after, you could then to `::Date` or `to_Date()`

Comment: I tried, TIMESTAMP_NTZ, TIMESTAMP, date all three but none seem to work and throw an error at the later stage :(

Comment: Can you see the edit in the qs

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, it seems to me you have 2 options.

Either you can get rid of the `+0000` at the end:
`left(column_date, len(column_date)-5)::timestamp`

or use the function `try_to_timestamp` with format:
`try_to_timestamp('2022-02-09T20:28:59+0000','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS+TZHTZM')`

`TZH` and `TZM`  both are **TimeZone Offset Hours** and **Minutes**